# Converting compass points to corresponding direction

Tags: r, function

I have created a function in R to convert compass points to the corresponding wind direction. Function is below.

```
windDirectionClassifier <- function(x) { 
  if(x == 1) y <- "North"
  if(x == 2) y <- "North North East"
  if(x == 3) y <- "North East"
  if(x == 4) y <- "East North East"
  if(x == 5) y <- "East"
  if(x == 6) y <- "East South East"
  if(x == 7) y <- "South East"
  if(x == 8) y <- "South South East"
  if(x == 9) y <- "South"
  if(x == 10) y <- "South South West"
  if(x == 11) y <- "South West"
  if(x == 12) y <- "West South West"
  if(x == 13) y <- "West"
  if(x == 14) y <- "West North West"
  if(x == 15) y <- "North West"
  if(x == 16) y <- "North North West"
  return(y)
}
```

I then run the function on the data but I am returned with an error message:

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'y' not found

Does anyone know how I could solve this? Many thanks.

Comment: You would have to define a value of y, which is dummy maybe, like y = 0 at the start of this if block. It would help in solving if you could attach the complete code snippet. Thanks!

Comment: It can be possible that your functon received an input that is outside of the 1-16 range that you defined for if conditions, e.g. `x = 0`, and that's why your function couldn't return y. As @srishtigarg suggested you need to define `y = 0` at the beginning of the if block. Also, please, provide either a full or simplified version of your function and expected inputs.

Comment: Defensive programming: design the function to do what you want given pristine input, then what to do when the caller provides something else. In this case, I'd start the function with `y <- "Unk"` or `y <- NA_character_`. Or better yet start with either a draconian `stopifnot(x > 0, x <= 16)` or `if (!is.numeric(x) || x < 1 || x > 16) stop("illegal 'x'")`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much guys. Following suggestion from 'srishtigarg', I checked and there are "0" values in the data which are errors. Thank you.